# StreamSubscription and StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter

I want to cancel a stream, and found that a `Stream` cannot be canceled, but a `StreamSubsciption` can be canceled. `Stream` object has a `listen()` method which

> Adds a subscription to this stream.

What actually is a subscription? and how do I use it with `StreamBuilder`?

From the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/StreamSubscription-class.html):

> A subscription on events from a Stream.
> When you listen on a Stream using Stream.listen, a StreamSubscription object is returned.
> The subscription provides events to the listener, and holds the callbacks used to handle the events. The subscription can also be used to unsubscribe from the events, or to temporarily pause the events from the stream.

From what I understand, I think I can use the `event` and use it to rebuild my widgets. Is it the right way to do it? or is there is a more correct way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using `StreamBuilder`, stream subscription and stream cancelling is managed by the framework. The `builder` method will be called when new snapshot is available, and when the widget is destroyed, stream subscription is cancelled.

As you wrote, you can create your own `StreamSubscription` with `listen()` method, and in this case you have to cancel this subscription when you no longer need it, for example in an overridden `dispose` method. To do so keep track of subscription in a variable or a member, assuming you have a stream in `stream` variable and `MyType` is the class which is returned by stream:

```
StreamSubscription<MyType> myStreamSubscription = stream.listen((value) {
  // add code here
});
```

Then you can use this to manage the stream:

```
myStreamSubscription.pause();
myStreamSubscription.resume();
myStreamSubscription.cancel();
```